# How to check the color profile of EPS files?

Tags: colors, rgb, file-format, eps

I need to programmatically check if an EPS vector file has one color profile. For example, I'd like to know if the file contains both RGB and CMYK color profiles.

Answer (score 1):

PostScript, and therefore by extension EPS, cannot contain colour profiles (assuming you mean ICC profiles).

If you mean you need to know if an EPS file uses both RGB and CMYK colour specifications, then that's a different issue. The easiest way to do that is to write a PostScript program which redefines the colour operators and reports their usage. Then run that and your EPS through a PostScript itnerpreter, such as Ghostscript.